# Using a specific JSON url in C# code

Tags: c#, json, data-extraction

I need to extract data from a JSON string from a specific url ([this](https://www.longboxed.com/api/v1/issues/thisweek/)).
When I convert it into C# by using jsontocsharp.com it looks like this:

```
public class Publisher
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int subscribers { get; set; }
}

public class Issue
{
    public List<object> alternates { get; set; }
    public string complete_title { get; set; }
    public string cover_image { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string diamond_id { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool is_parent { get; set; }
    public double? issue_number { get; set; }
    public string other { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public Publisher publisher { get; set; }
    public string release_date { get; set; }
    public Title title { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public List<Issue> issues { get; set; }
    public int next { get; set; }
    public object prev { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to use these as my classes so I can gather and use data on further layers of my project. But I don't know how should I put the url in my code. I think this is a very basic question but I couldn't quite get the answer I'm looking for in the other questions. Any help greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: You need to make an HTTP Request to that URL, and then handle the response. How you craft and send that request depends on what type of project you're working with. We can't give you a more concrete answer without knowing more about how your project is structured.

Comment: There's a few things you still need to handle at this point which makes this question quite broad.  Take a look at [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) for getting the data and then something like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for transforming it into objects.

Comment: For storing the actual URL, you can add that to your config file (App.config or Web.config), or access an external config file, which could be anything from an XML file or a flat text file. For larger applications, you may even want your configurations stored in your database so updating it in one place is all you would need to do.

Comment: start at http://restsharp.org/

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you for your help. I understood how to deserialize a JSON object by using Json.NET but now I need to get the Json string from that url by using HttpWebRequest which I'm having a hard time to figuring it out right now... I can't just copy-paste that Json string because it's getting updated in every week, that's why I need to pull it from that url automatically.